# Can't find sun.jdbc.odbc package in Java version 8

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to connect a database query to my class while I compile the package name `sun.jdbc.odbc` package but it is not found in Java version 8.

Comment: Do you have the JDK 8.0 installed?

Comment: This is more of a Java programming/configuration question than a DBA one - perhaps another forum might be an idea? If you do ask elsewhere, point a link back here though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22984438/440595

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has mentioned related to this in the Tec documents

> JDBC-ODBC Bridge The JDBC-ODBC Bridge allows applications written in
>   the Java programming language to use the JDBC API with many existing
>   ODBC drivers. The Bridge is itself a driver based on JDBC technology
>   ("JDBC driver") that is defined in the class
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver. The Bridge defines the JDBC sub-protocol
>   odbc.

And I think this is the reason why its not found in the Java version 8

> Status of the JDBC-ODBC Bridge The JDBC-ODBC Bridge should be
>   considered a transitional solution; **it will be removed in JDK 8**. In
>   addition, Oracle does not support the JDBC-ODBC Bridge. Oracle
>   recommends that you use JDBC drivers provided by the vendor of your
>   database instead of the JDBC-ODBC Bridge.

Source where the information was found [TechNotes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html),[Lance Andersen's Blog Removal of the JDBC-ODBC Bridge from Java SE 8 JDK](https://blogs.oracle.com/Lance/entry/removal_of_the_jdbc_odbc)

I suggest you try the following solutions

- Use a third-party database driver
- Use a previous version of java